# Why do modern systems set umasks to 0022 instead of 0002?

Tags: linux, default-settings, umask, default-profile

I never really got into this topic a lot, but from the good old days, I remember you'd want your umask to 0002 (so new files created are only writable by you, not by the group). Similar for directories.

I've noticed that on Ubuntu and friends as well as Fedora, CentOS on the other side of the camp.

What is the reason for this? Why are modern linux distributions making files group-writable by default?

Comment: It's a bit unclear.  You say modern systems are 022 but then you ask "Why are modern linux distributions making files group-writable by default?".  Do you mean to ask why aren't they group-writeable?

Comment: My guess would be that the decision either way likely revolves mostly around a particular stance regarding User Private Groups -- https://security.ias.edu/how-and-why-user-private-groups-unix